# Only check max date for specific rows?

Tags: sql

Edit: Realized there's tons of these questions. Trying a subquery and looking through those.

Edit2: Just needed a subquery. Works now. For the sake of anyone else looking at this, I added

```
where t2.startdate = (select max(startdate) from table2 as sub 
                      where sub.item = t1.item)
and t1.effectivedate = (select max(startdate) from table2 as sub2)
```

---

I'm currently writing a query to pull two rates from two separate tables, and return the difference between the two rates. I'm having trouble with getting the proper rates. I need to only get the rates for the most recent listing for each item. My data in the tables looks like this:

```
todate        item       rate
2014-01-15    pencil     -0.07
2014-01-17    pencil     -0.03
2014-02-22    pencil     -0.05
2014-01-15    pen        -0.013
2014-01-17    pen        -0.02
2014-02-22    pen        -0.032
```

I want it to return this (assuming both tables are exactly the same):

```
Item          Rate1        Rate2         Difference        Date
Pencil        -0.05        -0.05         0                 2014-02-22
Pen           -0.032       -0.032        0                 2014-02-22
```

Both tables are more or less the same thing, just with different rates. My problem is I end up getting multiple dates regardless of how I change the query.

I have this right now:

```
use db
select t1.item, t2.Rate as t2Rate, t1.Rate as t1Rate,(abs(t2.Rate) - abs(t1.Rate)) 
as Dffrnce, t2.startDate

from table2 as t2 join table1 as t1
on t2.item = t1.item
where t2.StartDate = t1.EffectiveDate
group by t1.item, t2.StartDate, t2.Rate, t1.Rate
having t2.StartDate = max(t2.StartDate)
order by t1.item
```

I'm guessing my problem is stemming from me not checking each item for their max date specifically. But I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I tried using distinct but that returned the same result.  Am I missing something obvious? I only want to grab the rates from the most recent date. I've tried joining on the item and max date, a having statement `having max(t2.StartDate) = t1.effectivedate` but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw your edit that says you got it working. Nice.

You might consider a different way to identify the rows you want to work with.

Which flavor of SQL are you using? Not everything works everywhere.

```
DECLARE @Rate1 AS TABLE (id INT, rateDate DATE, rate INT)
DECLARE @Rate2 AS TABLE (id INT, rateDate DATE, rate INT)

INSERT INTO @Rate1 (id, rateDate, rate) VALUES (1, '2000-01-01', 1),(1, '2001-01-01', 3),(2, '2000-01-01', 4)
INSERT INTO @Rate2 (id, rateDate, rate) VALUES (1, '2001-01-01', 2),(2, '2002-01-01', 3)

;WITH r1 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rateDate DESC) rn FROM @Rate1)
,     r2 AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY rateDate DESC) rn FROM @Rate2)
SELECT * 
  FROM r1 
       INNER JOIN 
       r2 ON r1.id=r2.id
WHERE r1.rn=1 
  AND r2.rn=1
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012. I'll take a look at that, once I get the time. Thankfully this only has to be run this once (as far as I know). Thanks for the suggestion!